# How can I create a URL blacklist with PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to blacklist certain URLs within my script. I want to block ALL subdomains, subfolders (www and non www versions), etc. based on the main URL. i.e...

```
subdomain.baddomain.com
baddomain.com/subfolder/file.php
www.baddomain.com/subfolder/file.php
```

Would a regular expression be best? If so, how?

Comment: How are you blocking them? Is this using `.htaccess`, are you doing it in PHP, or is it a different, strange solution?

Comment: Is this an Apache server? Probably easier to do it via .htaccess

Comment: The script is kind of like a bookmarking service. I want to block certain domains from being bookmarked. .htaccess wont work here

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url will probably be of use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
if(in_array(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST), $blacklist)) {
    //blacklisted addr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Corbin's answer will only block explict matches meaning you must input every domain/subdomain combination you want to block. This isn't a problem if you have only two domains such as "www.domain.com" & "domain.com". If you have dozens, hundreds or thousands then that would be a real headache. This function is a bit more robust as it checks if the banned domain string is in any part of the domain name, it's slower too :).

```
$bannedDomains = array('banned.com') // blocks top level & subdomains.
function bannedDomain($url, $bannedDomains) {
  $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_HOST_URL);
  foreach($bannedDomains as $bannedDomain) {
     if (strpos($domain, $bannedDomain) !== false) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

There is a caveat here as well, since it's blind string matching there is the off chance you could have someone do something like "www.banned.com.notbanned.com" as a domain name, since a banned domain string is within that domain, then you'd end up blocking a valid domain name. Domain matching & validation is actually pretty difficult given the variety of TLDs & subdomains that are out there.

Additionally, if you're okay with explicit matches only, it's more efficient to use your domains as keys in an associative array & then use isset() to detect if they are present in your banned list.

```
$bannedDomains = array(
 'www.banned.com' => true,
 'banned.com' => true
);

function bannedDomain($url, $bannedDomains) {
 $domain = parse_url($url, PHP_HOST_URL);
 return isset($bannedDomains[$domain]);
}
```

If you really need a super robust system then you're better off using a lookup inside a database or using your HTTP server's features.

Comment: I meant to mention that it would require a complete enumeration in my example but forgot. What could be done though is to parse the URL, then see if any banned domain is the complete string or the last part after a period. Also, good suggestion on the assoc array. I was thinking along the lines of a small set. (though if he ends up looping over them all will be a linear operation either way)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression, you need [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Comment: That won't work, how about otherdomain.com/foo/baddomain.com/bar?

Comment: @ChrisM I'd say that's too bad for them, use normal URL's, but if you insist, you can include the scheme (http://) in the comparison.